# New Item, Custom Form, Call Out(?)

Tags: list, custom-form, list-item, callouts

In my webpart when I click new item I get:

[image]
Is there a way to make this box appear to create a new list item when I link a link?

I want to have something hyperlinked like "Send Feedback" that people can click and get a callout box like this.

Let me know how to communicate my question better,
Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog` function to open a dialog like this:

```
function openURL(){

SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({ 
            url: "pageurl.aspx", 
            title: "Feedback", 
            allowMaximize: true, 
            showClose: true, 
            width: 800, 
            height: 600, 

            dialogReturnValueCallback: newCallback 
        });
function newCallback(dialogResult, returnValue) { 
       SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK); 
}
}
```

**Update**

You can use this function like

```
<button onclick="javascript:return openURL();">Feedback</button>
```

You can add a javascript file using the content web part.

*Edit page -> Add web part -> Media and content -> Content editor -> Add*

*Edit the source of the web part and add the following code into it:*

​`<script src="/sites/subsite/list/SiteAssets/file.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Add the js file under Site Assets using SharePoint Designer.

[image]

Comment: Can I ask you where I find functions? If you refer me to a site that will teach me about that i can look at it. Sounds like something in Designer?Thanks

Comment: Add a js file to your page and add the above code to it.

Comment: Do I add a content editor to the page to do this? I dont see in web parts where to add a js file. Very new at sharepoint.

Comment: Did you check my updated answer?

Comment: Click on Assets -> Javascript from the ribbon at the top or add an external file using Import Files button.

Comment: so i've added a .js file to site assets with the js functions. I've added the button to a sharepoint page, do I need to somehow get the js file on the page so the button knows where the function is?

Comment: Read my answer completely, I have written everything in that

Comment: I've spent some time reviewing what you've written and look at small tutorials on content editor and script editor.
I understand that the feedback button I create in script editor will be using the js openURL function. I think when I'm having a disconnect is understanding where the js function goes, and how it goes there.
In addition you say, "Edit the source of the web part and add the following code into it:" but I'm not sure where the "source" is to edit.
Thanks if you can help me understand this a bit better. Thanks for the patience.

Comment: See the screenshot

Comment: Thanks, and the js functions-?

Comment: Create a js file in your sharepoint designer under site assets and add your function in that

Comment: Sorry, but I've poured over this and looked at outside tutorials on inserting java pages into sp as well as scripts/content and I've tried putting this in in many different ways that seem like it would work to me. I'm a beginner and these steps aren't specific enough. Every time I just get a button that refreshes the page. Thanks for the attempted help, though.